# React Native Reanimated 'ScrollTo' Blocks Component Updates in Flatlist Child

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to use React Native Reanimated's '[ScrollTo](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/scroll/scrollTo/)' method to create an automatic scrolling component. However, this component is used in a FlatList, and my problem is that I cannot interact with anything else inside of the Flatlist while the animation is running.

Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJhQj.gif) of the behavior, outside and inside a FlatList.

And here is a link to that Snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/@spagrhetti/react-reanimated-in-flatlist-child?platform=ios

I have tried debugging by playing around with the different parameters (the WithTiming and WithRepeat values), but nothing seems to change the behavior. I am relatively new to React Native Reanimated, so please let me know if I am misusing the library.